# How to move image to the center of the div using inline css?

Tags: html, css

How to move image to the center of the div ?

[image]

I tried to use the text-align:center, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a quick tip ? Huge thanks ahead from me :) !

```
<!-- Logo -->
@if( $user->logo_path)
<img class=" img-rounded" style="text-align:center;" src="/files/logo_path/{{$user->id}}" alt="logo" width="100" >   
@else
<img class=" img-rounded " style="text-align:center;" src="/img/default.PNG" alt="logo"  width="100" >
@endif
```

Comment: Have you tried using margin: 0 auto? I think you need to show your css and the parent element to make a better answer

Comment: I thought this is quick fix. I already fix, but thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply the `text-align:center` property to the parent div of the `< img >` element, provided that your `< img >` element doesn't have any kind of positioning to it.

And see to it that the `< img >` element doesn't have the `display:block` property to it, if it does then change it to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent_div" style="text-align:center;">
    <!-- Logo -->
    @if( $user->logo_path)
    <img class=" img-rounded" src="/files/logo_path/{{$user->id}}" alt="logo" width="100" >   
    @else
    <img class=" img-rounded " src="/img/default.PNG" alt="logo"  width="100" >
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add block display and an automatic horizontal margin. `text-align` will only affect child elements and not the element's alignment itself.

```
<img class="img-rounded" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" src="/files/logo_path/{{$user->id}}" alt="logo" width="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=" col-lg-2" >

<div style="text-align:center">
    <!-- Logo -->
    @if( $user->logo_path)

    <img class=" img-rounded" style="text-align:center;" src="/files/logo_path/{{$user->id}}" alt="logo" width="100" >

    @else

    <img class=" img-rounded " style="text-align:center;" src="/img/default.PNG" alt="logo"  width="100" >

    @endif

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You do not need `text-align:center` on the individual imgs.